# Struts Action class is not calling

Tags: javascript, java, struts, struts-1

I am using the following code inside javascript to call a  action class.

```
 document.ParserForm.action="<%=ctx%>/DeleteList.do?id=" +id; 
 document.ParserForm.submit();
```

`DeleteList` is the action path i have configured in struts-config.xml file.

`ParserForm` is my `FormBean` name, but while calling that javascript, the action class is not being called. What could be the cause of it?

Comment: try debugging with any of the web developer tools (chrome, firefox...) and check the url which the form is making the `POST` request to, make sure it is your desired action's URL :)

Comment: What value is `ctx`?

Comment: it could be something that runs before the action is executed and it failed. You have to debug your app to find the cause.

Comment: ctx is the context path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
document.ParserForm.action="<%=ctx%>/DeleteList.do"; 
document.ParserForm.submit();
```